# ObservableCollection with Range causes issues with UI

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have a program that displays a list of items and each item has some additional detail that can be shown and hidden with a button.  The source collection is a custom class called ObservableCollectionWithRange which is just a simple extension of ObservableCollection that allows you to add objects in bulk (I believe I got it from somewhere on here but don't remember).  Here is the code for it:

```
public class ObservableCollectionWithRange<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        this.CheckReentrancy();

        foreach (var item in items)
            this.Items.Add(item);

        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
    public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        this.CheckReentrancy();
        foreach (var item in items)
            this.Items.Remove(item);

        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}
```

My program also loads these items using pagination (loads the first 10 and if the user scrolls down far enough loads the next 10, etc.).  Now here is the weird bug.  If I do an initial search and it displays the first set of results I can show the additional detail and everything looks fine.  However, if I collapse the detail, then scroll to the bottom so it loads the next set, then re-expand the same item, the details are just blank.

Here is what it is supposed to look like and what it does look like on the first time:

[image: The correct view]

Here is what it looks like after expanding, closing, then loading the next set:

[image]

(I know they are different objects, these are taken from different searches, but it does happen with the same object).

The strangest thing is that I checked the code and the objects are still there, the list of objects that is displayed in the details is still there, and all the properties are correct.  It also does create a ListViewItem for each of the detail items which is why it's a tall white space instead of a thin one, it's just that the data that it's supposed to show is blank.

I do have some custom styles applied for ListView and ListViewItem but I tried removing them and it was the same (except for the styling of course).

Now here is the kicker.  I switched to adding items one at a time instead of using the 'AddRange' capability... and it works normally.  Since I'm not adding a lot of items at once this is probably a workable solution for me, but it has me seriously scratching my head wondering what in the world is causing this behavior and I'd like to understand it.

Here is the relevant code for the control that shows the details:

```
<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding ShowParameters, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
                <TextBlock Text="Dimensions" Style="{StaticResource st_SearchTitles}" />
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DimensionParameters}" Style="{StaticResource st_ListViewNoScroll}"
                          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource st_ListViewNoSelection}">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource st_ColumnHeaderBlank}">
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Definition.Name}" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
                <TextBlock Text="Classifications" Style="{StaticResource st_SearchTitles}" />
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ClassificationParameters}" Style="{StaticResource st_ListViewNoScroll}"
                          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource st_ListViewNoSelection}">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource st_ColumnHeaderBlank}">
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Definition.Name}" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
                <TextBlock Text="Properties" Style="{StaticResource st_SearchTitles}" />
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyParameters}" Style="{StaticResource st_ListViewNoScroll}"
                          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource st_ListViewNoSelection}">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource st_ColumnHeaderBlank}">
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Definition.Name}" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
                <TextBlock Text="Formulas" Style="{StaticResource st_SearchTitles}" />
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FormulaParameters}" Style="{StaticResource st_ListViewNoScroll}"
                          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource st_ListViewNoSelection}">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource st_ColumnHeaderBlank}">
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Definition.Name}" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Formula}" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
                <TextBlock Text="Links" Style="{StaticResource st_SearchTitles}" />
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding UrlParameters}" Style="{StaticResource st_ListViewNoScroll}"
                          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource st_ListViewNoSelection}">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource st_ColumnHeaderBlank}">
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Definition.Name}" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource st_ToolButton}" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="btn_Collapse">
                    <Image Source="../Images/Glyph_Contract.png" Stretch="None">
                        <Image.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Image">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowParameters}" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="45" />
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-5,0,0" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowParameters}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="-135" />
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,-5" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Image.Style>
                    </Image>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
```

As you can see the details is just a stack panel with a handful of ListViews and a visibility based on the 'ShowParameters' boolean parameter from the view model.  There is a button that shows it but it just toggles that property.  The ItemsSource for the listviews are just CollectionViewSource objects with different filters that are based on a common collection.

Does anyone know what is happening here and/or how to make the AddRange work properly?

Comment: Hard to tell exactly, but most likely that is because you use `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset`. That means collection has completely changed (default observable collection uses it only if you call Clear). So all UI controls should be completely redrawn and that somehow causes what you see. Hard to tell more without more code (related to how you display that details).

Comment: I added the XAML code for the details portion and a brief explanation of relevant points.  I know reset makes it redraw and that has to be the difference but I don't understand why.  If you redraw all of them then why would that make it create some type of blank object? Especially on the sub-list?  It's the collection of main objects that is being reset and I'm confused as to why that would affect the objects on that item...